# Disable BLOB logging in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Is there a way to disable/truncate BLOB fields in the logged SQL queries? When I insert or update a record with BLOB fields in it Rails logger prints the contents of these fields which is very annoying. I found some solutions but none of them work with Rails 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a couple of things you can do, one would be to override the Logger format_message function and remove BLOB fields from the logger message:

```
class Logger
  def remove_blobs msg
    ...
  end

  def format_message(severity, timestamp, progname, msg)
    "#{remove_blobs msg}\n"
  end
end
```

The next would be to add your blob fields to the filter_parameters in your application.rb file. This would mean that the blob fields would be filtered from your application logs entirely:

```
config.filter_parameters += [:blob_field1, :blob_field2]
```

Finally, you could look into some other logging gems, like [logging](https://rubygems.org/gems/logging), to add further customization to your logs.