# How to disable activerecord cache logging in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, activerecord, logging

I'm trying to disable logging of caching in production. Have succeeded in getting SQL to stop logging queries, but no luck with caching log entries.  Example line in production log:

```
CACHE (0.0ms) SELECT `merchants`.* FROM `merchants` WHERE `merchants`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
```

I do not want to disable all logging, since I want logger.debug statements to show up in the production log.
Using rails 3.2.1 with Mysql and Apache.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I would like to know how to do the same thing using rails 2.3.5

Answer (score 3):

Rails 5.1

```
# config/initializers/active_record_logger.rb

class CacheFreeLogger < ActiveSupport::Logger
  def add(severity, message = nil, progname = nil, &block)
    return true if progname&.include? "CACHE"
    super
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.logger = CacheFreeLogger.new(STDOUT)
```

Answer (score 2):

I silenced the CACHE log using the method suggested by the post linked below.

I replaced the default ActiveRecod logger with a wrapper that filters off messages containing unwanted texts i.e. 'CACHE'.

First, create a file inside `config/initializers` for example `active_record.rb` and inside the file define a wrapper class and replace the active record logger like in the code below:

```
# Implementation of logger that ignores messages containing forbidden words
# here “CACHE” and "Settings Load"
class CacheFreeLogger < ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging

  @@excluded = ['Settings Load','CACHE']

  def add(severity, message = nil, progname = nil, &block)
    if message.nil?
      if block_given?
        message = block.call
      else
        message = progname
        progname = nil #No instance variable for this like Logger
      end
    end
    if severity > Logger::DEBUG ||  !(@@excluded.map{|e| message.include? e}.include?(true))
        @logger.add(severity, "#{tags_text}#{message}", progname)
    end
  end
end

#Replace the existing logger with the filtering one
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = CacheFreeLogger.new(ActiveRecord::Base.logger) if Rails.env.development?
```

The original post extended Logger not TaggedLoggin but it did not work for me.

This method was suggested in the blog: http://heliom.ca/blog/posts/disable-rails-cache-logging

Answer (score -3):

There are a few questions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522961/rails-activerecord-how-can-i-turn-off-logging-particular-queries), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759321/disable-rails-3-1-sql-logging), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966948/turn-off-verbose-sql-activerecord-for-rails-3-1-1)) like this on SO all with a similar theme. You could try putting this in an initializer file:

```
old_logger = ActiveRecord::Base.logger
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = nil
```

Restore logger:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = old_logger; nil # nil just to suppress some garbage
```

Comment: How is your answer related to `CACHE (0.0ms)`-like entries?